# ASCII символы в linux

Tags: c++, linux

В программе на С++ нужно выводить на экран некоторые символы, которые имеют графическое представление в таблице ASCII. gnome-terminal вместо них либо ничего не рисует, либо какие-то странные знаки (не такие, как нужно). Какие быть может есть способы получить аналогичные символам ASCII символы, например, в UTF-8 средствами С/С++?

Comment: Подумайте, в какой локале у вас консоль терминала и что вы пытаетесь вывести.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам помогут таблицы псевдографики Unicode:

> Рамки - [Unicode Box Drawing Chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf)
> Фоны и блоки - [Unicode Block Elements Chart](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2580.pdf)

Не забудьте, что коды в таблице из пространства UCS, а в UTF-8 еще нужно преобразовать, при этом символы из набора U+2500 - U+25FF кодируются в UTF-8 тремя байтами каждый, например, символ с UCS-кодом U+2500 кодируется последовательностью e2 94 80.

Как вариант построения собственной таблицы кодов - скопировать таблицу из [статьи в Википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character), вставить в текстовый документ, убрать пробелы и переводы строк и распарсить простенькой программой, отрезая по три байта. Я однажды так и сделал (времени изобретать менее костыльный вариант просто не было).

Answer (score 2):

Напишите, конкретно какие коды и что Вы хотите увидеть на экране.

Кстати, ASCII это от 0 до 127 (включительно). Вы м.б. хотите увидеть псевдографику из cp866? Тогда попробуйте перекодировать, используя команду iconv.

Например, `iconv -c -f cp866 -t utf-8 ./my-file`  выведет на экран в utf-8

Для программирования этого на C посмотрите man 3 iconv.